# Enums in DAO don't have the regular system methods?

Tags: ms-access, enums, vba, dao

I'm trying to get the datatype out of a DAO recordset.  Code below:

```
Public Function EditFormData(frm As Form)
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fieldType as DAO.DataTypeEnum

  Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone
  rst.MoveFirst

  fieldType = rst.Fields(0).Type
  MsgBox fieldType.ToString
```

I get an Invalid Qualifier error on fieldType in the msgbox when I try to run this, and don't know why since this is my first foray into Enums.

Comment: Docs state that `Type` returns an integer result, not an enum. See also:  http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html

Comment: @TimWilliams my understanding was that the returned integer corresponds to a data type entry in DAO.DataTypeEnum, so I was trying to get the corresponding string.  The function you linked to however, depicts hard coding each value and it's string correspondent in order to convert from the integer back to the string, basically leaving the built in enum with that information out of it.  I was hoping to avoid doing that, but if there's no easier way I can.  Thank you for the link.

Comment: Enums in VB[A] don't have that handy "ToString()" method.  Hand-coding the string values in a function isn't fun, but luckily someone already did it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own function to convert the enum to text.  Instead of writing the code from scratch I found this example.

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/209125-can-you-tell-datatype-control

PS My first post or comment so feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the current position of the recordset is? If it is at EOF, then you will be in trouble. Try calling rst.MoveFirst before getting the field type.

Comment: Fixed it.  it was there in my original code, just missed it in the copy.

Comment: Should clarify that I fixed the post with rst.MoveFirst, I'm still having problems with the original issue

Comment: The Type property is actually defined as an Integer. I would try defining fieldtype as an integer too.